# Use System.Linq.Expressions.Expression and System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression classes in .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, .net

In my project i am using .NET 3.0 (it is a restriction). 
Now I need to use `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`  and `System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression` classes. 
Is there any re-implementation of that classes, so that i can use them ? 
  *Something like [LinqBridge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqBridge/)*

Comment: *Why* do you need to use them? And why is the .NET 3 restriction in place? It's a lot easier to help you if we have context - otherwise we could suggest things which are prohibited for the same reasons.

Comment: @JonSkeet .NET 3.0 is restriction, because App should run on machines that do not have higher version of .NET installed than 3.0.

Comment: What machines do you have in mind? .NET 4.5 is installed on the *vast* majority of machines today... although you only need to go to .NET 3.5 to get expression trees. You still haven't answered what you're trying to do with expression trees, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet Its my Company's customers computer, i do not know how can i be more specific about this. Specifically i am trying to rebuild some `Devexpress` library to run on .NET 3.0.

Comment: Well if you're trying to rebuild a library designed for a later version of .NET, I suspect you're going to have a hard time. I would push back on the .NET 3.0 requirement if you *possibly* can. (.NET 3.5 was released in 2008 - it's 2016 now. Have your customers really not updated their computers since then? There may well be all kinds of security issues...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon for suggestion but, Unfortunately they are still using old computer's. That company (Bank) has too many such users, in order to renew computers.

Comment: Well missing important Windows updates (such as later versions of .NET) is a security risk... but basically, I would suggest avoiding trying to use any modern libraries which assume .NET 3.5+ if you can't actually make that framework available.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks jon, if i had a way to avoid `Devexpress` modern library i should, but i do not have.

Comment: Then you should *at least* warn the stakeholders that they have conflicting requirements (using a library which requires version X while they refuse to make sure that that version is available). Warn them that this will at the very least add time (and therefore cost), and may well cause issue. It's very likely that this won't be a supported environment for the DevExpress library, too...

Comment: .NET 3.0 and 3.5 use CLR 2.0, so it is a low risk operation to install 3.5 on a machine that already has 3.0. Any application that was installed by the stakeholders with .NET 3.0 will continue to work. You could offer the customer two choices: 1) require .NET 3.5 and target development for that version; 2) have you implement your own expression trees, which will take longer, cost more and incur greater risk.

Comment: @S.Rojak Thanks, Unfortunately , installing .NET 3.5 on machines was refused by customer.